# Datastax driver Metrics on Datadog

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Can any one help me in getting the Datastax driver Metrics to Datadog.

Tried to search but no luck and was not able find any.

The following are the [metrics](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/Metrics.html) that we need to se in the dataDog.

Comment: For what reason this was down voted?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Datadog's Agent to collect metrics via a JMX connection.  There is documentation found here:

http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-jmx-metrics-with-datadog/

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204501525-Custom-JMX-Integration-s-

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/207525586-View-jmx-data-in-jConsole-and-set-up-your-jmx-yaml-to-collect-them

That should help you get setup and collecting the necessary metrics exposed by your JMX port.

That said, if you encounter any issues reach out to support@datadoghq.com and they can assist you.